# Minimum components re-renders when using input with onChange

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form with two inputs `InputComp1` and `InputComp2`. I'm wrapping them in `ReusableForm`. When i type, both the  `InputComp*` and `ReusableForm` are being re-rerendered.

I do understand this is because when I'm passing new value to one of the Input components state it changes thus causing re-render for that component. I also do understand because I'm passing `children` in `ReusableForm` it does cause re-render for that component also because children prop has changed.

I have tried wrapping those component in `memo` but that did not work, i do also think if i use something like Redux that this would solve the problem, but I'm trying to use just React and it's own state for this.

So I'm trying to work out, when having this structure and when i type in the input fields can i reduce the re-rendering happening for both `ReusableForm` and `InputComp*` components?

CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-water-xtymi?file=/src/App.js

App.tsx

```
import { Container } from './components/_Forms/Container'

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  return <Container />
}
```

Container.tsx

```
import { InputComp1 } from './InputComp1'
import { InputComp2 } from './InputComp2'

export const Container: React.FC = () => {
  console.log(' ~ Container')

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#e59393', padding: '20px' }}>
      <InputComp1 />
      <InputComp2 />
    </div>
  )
}
```

ReusableForm

```
export const ReusableForm: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(' ~ ReusableForm')

  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

InputComp1, but also same for InputComp2

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ReusableForm } from './ReusableForm'

export const InputComp1 = () => {
  const [state, stateSet] = useState('')

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    stateSet(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  console.log(' ~ InputComp1')

  return (
    <ReusableForm>
      <div>{state}</div>
      <input type="text" value={state} onChange={onChange} />
    </ReusableForm>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can use debounce to reduce the setState frequency.

Comment: @MehulThakkar Not without other changes, as then the visually typed input would also be *debounced*.

Comment: @Marius You might use an [uncontrolled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Comment: In case if you need the state change to be reflected immediately then I agreen with @yoshi. Use Uncontrolled input or `react-hook-form`. That'll help